# Retrieving Queued Messages on Remote Federation Upstream in Rabbitmq

Tags: amazon-web-services, rabbitmq, google-compute-engine, federation, queueing

I've recently been working on setting up RabbitMQ clusters on Google Computer Engine and AWS connected via federation.  So far I've been able to get that working fine although I've encountered an issue that I can't figure out how to solve.

At a certain point, I wanted to see what would happen if I deleted all the VMs in the GCE cluster to then re-create them.  I was able to bring the cluster back up, but the AWS cluster exchange that was previously federated, continued to hold the queued messages, even after a new federation link was created from GCE to AWS.  All new messages on the AWS cluster were being retrieved via the federation link, but the old queued messages were not being sent also.

How could I get these old messages to also be sent onto the new federation link?

Answer (score 1):

If the messages are already queued in the remote server, then you probably want to use shovel to solve this problem: https://www.rabbitmq.com/shovel.html